# Angularjs - How to get value in function 1 in function 2 of same controller

Tags: angularjs, function

My Angularjs Controller is like this :

```
$scope.fn1 = function(){
//do something A
 var A = 122;
};

$scope.fn2 = function(){
   //do something B
   //I want to get var A here
}
```

I want to get value of var A in fn2. How can I get that?

Comment: with `$scope.A` or declare it outside of this function, in controller; remember that doing so `A` will have a globally value(common for fn1 and fn2)

Comment: Do you know you should accept best answer to make community effective, if somebody searching same problem they will see the best answer first. Please accept one of below answers –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define value of `A` outside the function `fn1`

```
var A = 122; // or $scope.A = 122;
   $scope.fn1 = function(){
    //do something A
   };
   $scope.fn2 = function(){
       //do something B
       //I want to get var A here
   }
```

Or

Call Function B in function A.

```
$scope.fn1 = function(){
//do something A
 var A = 122;
 $scope.fn2(A);
};

$scope.fn2 = function(value){
   //do something B
   //I want to get var A here
}
```

But in case you are defining it in $scope & inside function 2, that is also not a good practice if there are chances to call function 2 before function 1

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly your context, but I think A must be a property of your scope:

```
$scope.fn1 = function(){
   //do something A
   $scope.A = 122;
};

$scope.fn2 = function(){
   //do something B
   //I want to get var A here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a global `$scope.A` instead of `var A`

```
$scope.A = 0;

$scope.fn1 = function(){
//do something  to change A
 $scope.A = 122;
};

$scope.fn2 = function(){
   //do something B
   var abc = $scope.A;
   console.log(abc);
}
```

`abc should return 123,` hope this is the answer you're looking for! `$scope` is a global variable, and could be changed/used throughout the entire controller :)

Comment: console.log returns undefined. And if I initialise it with 0, it returns 0 .

Comment: hmm, $scope.fn1 and $scope.fn2 are in the same controller right? did you set $scope.A = 122; in $scope.fn1?

Comment: yes, I also checked by setting $scope.A =122. But still undefined.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9751/ this is my fiddle to it, check it out. when you click on the button, it launches fn2 and shows that $scope.A is 123. @Mohammed